# Extract Data from .txt files and export it to a .csv file #powershell

Tags: powershell

I am a beginner in Powershell, and I need some help. Thanks in advance

**Requirement:**

1. Get files inside a folder by browsing with a Folderbrowser.
2. Get the data inside the different .txt files.
3. Paste it into a single sheet of a .csv table.

   ```
   Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
   $FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
   [void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
   $Selection = $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath

   $input = Get-ChildItem $Selection

   $objects = ForEach($record in $data) 
   {
       $props = @{}
       foreach($input in $Selection)
       {
           $records +=Get-Content $data
           $props.Add($records)
       }
   }

   $AllFilesData =  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $props

   $path = $Selection+"\"+"AllFilesTogether.csv"
   $objects | Select-Object AllFilesData| Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $path
   ```

**Error:**

> Get-Content : Cannot find path
>   'D:\users\F14897c\sd_conex_france_20170107002029.txt' because it does
>   not exist. 
>   At line:14 char:15
>   +    $records +=Get-Content $data
>   +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\users\F14897...70107002029.txt:String) [Get-Content],
>   ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand   Cannot
>   find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1".
>
> At line:16
>   char:9
>   +         $props.Add($records)
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest

Comment: What do you expect the resulting csv file to look like? Just a single column where each row is a line from a file inside the folder?

Comment: Yes,This is exactly what i am trying to do

Comment: What are you expecting $data to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single-column CSV file is just a list of strings, so your script can be simplified immensely:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
[void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()
$Selection = $FolderBrowser.SelectedPath

Get-ChildItem $Selection -Filter *.txt |Get-Content |Out-File (Join-Path $Selection AllFilesTogether.csv)
```

Comment: one of the best i have seen

Answer (score 1):

You obviously aren't giving the whole code, as $data in the ForEach loop is never defined. Regardless, the reason why you are getting the errors is that you need to change:

```
$records +=Get-Content $data
```

to

```
$records +=Get-Content $data.FullName
```

Assuming that $data is the result of a Get-ChildItem.

Also, you are trying to add to a hash table with 1 argument, which isn't going to fly either. You will need to supply a key value pair. If you are only going to use one column, then declare an array with @() instead of a Hash table.